# How to trigger a page Redirect within componentWillReceiveProps?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux

My page/component outputs a form that upon submission calls my backend API. If successful, it returns an object that I add to my redux store.

I use `componentWillReceiveProps` in order to know in my component whether or not the reducer successfully added the object to my store's property. I included Redirect from redux-router.

```
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {

    if( nextProps.user.activeSubscriptions ) {
        this.props.user.activeSubscriptions = nextProps.user.activeSubscriptions;
    }

    if( Object.keys(nextProps.user.properties).length != Object.keys(this.props.user.properties).length ) {
        console.log("lets redirect.."); // this works
        return (<Redirect to={"/account/properties"} />); // this doesn't...
    }
}
```

How can I trigger a redirect within that if() statement in my `componentWillReceiveProps`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `window.location='/account/properties';` there, instead of         `return (<Redirect to={"/account/properties"} />); // this doesn't...`

Another approach will be to add an extra property to your default state, something like this:

```
this.state = { userChanged: false };
```

And you'll need to add a setState on componentWillReceiveProps if that case is valid so React knows that it should trigger the render method again, something like this:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {

    if( nextProps.user.activeSubscriptions ) {
        this.props.user.activeSubscriptions = nextProps.user.activeSubscriptions;
    }

    if( Object.keys(nextProps.user.properties).length != Object.keys(this.props.user.properties).length ) {
        console.log("lets redirect.."); // this works
        this.setState({userChanged: true});
    }
}
```

Then on your render method:

```
render() {
    if(this.state.userChanged) {
        return (<Redirect to={"/account/properties"} />);
    }
// Your other code goes here...

}
```

Comment: it does work but it reloads the whole page to go to that URL (which is fine if it's the only solution... but is it?)

Comment: I'll add a new approach.

Comment: or you could go `this.rekt = 'account/properties;` and in `render(){ return <div>{this.rekt && <Redirect to={this.rekt} />} ... more stuff</div> }`

Comment: This will not work as updating this.rekt value will not generate a re-render, I added a new approach that will use state to do something like that.

Comment: If you are using Router v4 , you can try this :  this.props.history.push('/account/properties');

Comment: @Martin it will work because you've just gotten props. render cycle will take place anyway

Comment: Thats true but not in all the cases, we should look for shouldComponentUpdate code.

Comment: You can also do `ReactDOM.render(<Redirect />, someEl)`

Comment: perfect - works with your full solution and with no redirect. thanks! marked as answer!